# Upgrade from 64-bit 16.10 to 17.04 fails

Tags: upgrade

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libubuntu-app-launch4 : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2) but 0.9+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 ubuntu-app-launch-tools : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2) but 0.9+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 url-dispatcher-tools : Depends: url-dispatcher (= 0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu2) but 0.1+16.10.20160816.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

fix-broken ... does not work

```
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-app-launch_0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-app-launch_0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 there is no script in the new version of the package - giving up
Preparing to unpack .../url-dispatcher_0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/url-dispatcher_0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 there is no script in the new version of the package - giving up
Preparing to unpack .../click-apparmor_0.3.18_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/click-apparmor_0.3.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-app-launch_0.12+17.04.20170404.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/url-dispatcher_0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/click-apparmor_0.3.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Same error here!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar errors, and these commands helped me:

```
sudo apt autoremove -f click click-apparmor ubuntu-app-launch
reboot
sudo apt --fix-broken install  
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```